# Is anyone facing an indentation problem issue at replit.com? I am seeing an indentation error in replit which is not there in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, indentation, replit

[An error in line 39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnSK.png)

```
Error in console of replit:
  File "main.py", line 39
    for item in a_list:
                      ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I tried the same code in PyCharm:

```
def mutate(a_list):
  b_list = []
  for item in a_list:
    new_item = item * 2
    b_list.append(new_item)
  print(b_list)

mutate([1,2,3,5,8,13])
```

and everything works well!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code visually,  Often, this represents a mixing of tabs and spaces, or accidentally including a non-breaking space, which of course LOOKS just like a regular space.  I suggest you cut-and-paste the block from your working PyCharm window.

Comment: Thanks so much @TimRoberts , the copy-pasting from PyCharm works but I wish I could tweak some settings in replit to fix it for good. Sometimes I face this issue when I am writing bigger programs. As I am a beginner, it confuses me a lot!